# How do I get my winsxs folder to be smaller on windows 7, above and beyond all of the standard disk clean up?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, winsxs

I'm running my computer on a small 100GB SSD. I noticed that there was 22GB left on it, and I started to investigate.

The biggest culprit on my machine was a 32GB WinSxS folder. I was flabbergasted.

I have followed every article I could find on Google to size this folder down, but despite my efforts, the folder is still just above 10GB!

How can I size this folder down even more? Preferably to 0, lol.

Is there a way that won't screw up my computer? I am in total disbelief that I have a folder that is larger than everything else on this drive, and for all I know, I likely will never need it.

Thanks

Comment: If you reduce it to 0 you won't be able to repair your installation if it becomes corrupt, even at 10GB, you likely have liminated the capability

Comment: Well, like I said, I followed all of the advice to trim it down. The smallest I got to was 10GB. It just makes me want to reinstall a fresh copy of windows to maybe see if I can reclaim 10GB of space.

Comment: Dude, WinSxS IS your operating system!